# Left-side navigationView in Sencha Touch Framework (A question about Ext.data.TreeStore)

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I want to dynamically set up the left-side navigation menu just like iPad-style.
So, I make some modification on the demo example. You could also visit this official example [here](http://pydictionary.appspot.com/).

```
sink.StructureStore = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'Demo',
    //root: {
    //    items: sink.Structure
    //},
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'words.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

For easier implementation, I try to get the JSON data from the "words.json".
(Ideally, JSONP type is better...tried, but no luck.)

Here is the content of "words.json":

```
{
    text: 'User Interface',
    cls: 'launchscreen',
    items: [{
        text: 'Buttons',
        card: demos.Buttons,
        source: 'src/demos/buttons.js',
        leaf: true
    },  
    {   
        text: 'Forms',
        card: demos.Forms,
        source: 'src/demos/forms.js',
        leaf: true
    },  
    {   
        text: 'List',
        card: demos.List,
        source: 'src/demos/list.js',
        leaf: true
    }]  
}
```

It ends up nothing appearing. What's wrong? Do I mistake it? (API [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/TreeStore.html#cls-Ext.data.TreeStore))

#### What do I want to do?

Like a dictionary, left side are those navigation items of word. On clicking it, the meaning of the word will be showed in right-side view.

I can't run NestedList example in  [sencha framework](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/). **Clicking on the table cell and push another view on it** (i.e., in Sencha: NestedList) is what I want to do.

#### Have tried and no luck:

1. use the NestedList example
2. replace proxy with ScriptTagProxy (JSONP)
3. use easier proxy implementation (showed in the code)

I am not so sure whether my description is clear enough or not, feel free to tell me which part is unclear. And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If words.json looks like what you have above then that could be your problem.

This is what it should look like.

```
{
    "text": "User Interface",
    "cls": "launchscreen",
    "items": [{
        "text": "Buttons",
        "source": "src/demos/buttons.js",
        "leaf": true
    }, {
        "text": "Forms",
        "source": "src/demos/forms.js",
        "leaf": true
    }, {
        "text": "List",
        "source": "src/demos/list.js",
        "leaf": true
    }]
}
```

I've also attached a fully working copy of what you wanted using both a memory proxy (default) and an ajax proxy.

```
Ext.regApplication({
    name: 'test',
    launch : function(){
        var nL = new Ext.NestedList({
            store: test.stores.testTreeStore,
            fullscreen: true,
            itemTextTpl : '{text}'
        });
    }
});
Ext.ns('test.data');

test.data.words = {
    text: 'User Interface',
    cls: 'launchscreen',
    items: [{
        text: 'Buttons',
        source: 'src/demos/buttons.js',
        leaf: true
    },  
    {   
        text: 'Forms',
        source: 'src/demos/forms.js',
        leaf: true
    },  
    {   
        text: 'List',
        source: 'src/demos/list.js',
        leaf: true
    }]  
};

test.models.testTreeModel = Ext.regModel('testTreeModel', {
    fields: ['text','source','card','leaf'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        data: test.data.words,
        //type: 'ajax',
        //url: 'words.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
test.stores.testTreeStore = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'testTreeModel'
});
```